# How to create confusion matrix from indices output

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I am working on image modelling using keras. I am getting the following output after model fitting: (Multi-label classification)

```
len(test_generator):5

test_generator.classe:   

>[[0,2],[1,3],[0,1,2],[3,1,2,0],[2,1]]

Predictions as:

predicted_class_indices:  (predicted_class_indices=np.argmax(pred_prob,axis=1)
predicted_class_indices 
    >[3,3,0,1,2]

Prediction_genres:

>['Comedy', 'Comedy', 'Action', 'Adventure', 'Animation']

Labels_map:

>{'Action': 0, 'Adventure': 1, 'Animation': 2, 'Comedy': 3, 'Crime': 4}
```

I am trying to generate confusion matrix as below"

```
print(confusion_matrix(test_generator.classes,Prediction_genres))
```

I am getting the following error:

ValueError: You appear to be using a legacy multi-label data representation. Sequence of sequences are no longer supported; use a binary array or sparse matrix instead.